# How to get previous timezone as part of significantTimeChangeNotification in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, notifications, timezone

I have a use case where I need to detect the change in the timezone and track it in my app DB. I see that we can use the significantTimeChangeNotification to get notified when there is a significant change in time. But I also need to track the previous timezone before the change occurred. I could think of fetching the previous timezone from the last entry of the DB, but is there a graceful way of getting it from the notification?

Comment: The `significantTimeChangeNotification` notification does not provide any information of any kind. All you know is that the time changed for one of many possible reasons.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is, you can use the `NSTimeZone` class to store the current timezone in a variable.
When you receive then the `significantTimeChangeNotification` you can retrieve the timezone stored in the previous variable and compare it with the current timezone.